# Android build failed after ejecting from expo managed workflow

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

```
The Kotlin Gradle plugin was loaded multiple times in different subprojects, which is not supported and may break the build. 
This might happen in subprojects that apply the Kotlin plugins with the Gradle 'plugins { ... }' DSL if they specify explicit versions, even if the versions are equal.
Please add the Kotlin plugin to the common parent project or the root project, then remove the versions in the subprojects.
If the parent project does not need the plugin, add 'apply false' to the plugin line.
See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl
The Kotlin plugin was loaded in the following projects: ':expo', ':expo-modules-core'

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/Users/rahulkumar/Documents/learning-react-native/FavouritePlaces/android/app/src/main/java/com/rahulkumarmbd/FavouritePlaces/MainApplication.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
               ^
  symbol: variable BuildConfig
/Users/rahulkumar/Documents/learning-react-native/FavouritePlaces/android/app/src/main/java/com/rahulkumarmbd/FavouritePlaces/MainApplication.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
        return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
               ^
  symbol: variable BuildConfig
/Users/rahulkumar/Documents/learning-react-native/FavouritePlaces/android/app/src/main/java/com/rahulkumarmbd/FavouritePlaces/MainApplication.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
        return BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED;
               ^
  symbol: variable BuildConfig
/Users/rahulkumar/Documents/learning-react-native/FavouritePlaces/android/app/src/main/java/com/rahulkumarmbd/FavouritePlaces/MainApplication.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
        ^
  symbol:   variable BuildConfig
  location: class MainApplication
/Users/rahulkumar/Documents/learning-react-native/FavouritePlaces/android/app/src/main/java/com/rahulkumarmbd/FavouritePlaces/MainActivity.java:19: error: package R does not exist
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
              ^
/Users/rahulkumar/Documents/learning-react-native/FavouritePlaces/android/app/src/main/java/com/rahulkumarmbd/FavouritePlaces/MainActivity.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
    return new ReactActivityDelegateWrapper(this, BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED, new DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable BuildConfig
  location: class MainActivity
6 errors
```

I am running this command expo run:android after eject , i want it to be successfully. I have tried multiple approaches which was suggested by chat GPT. like to add it in build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.6.10'
    // other plugins...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this issue was occuring due to `namespace` in android of `android/app/build.gradle` file, it was something else i.e. `myfavouriteplaces` and was expecting this , after this i am able to resolve this issue

> com.rahulkumarmbd.FavouritePlaces